# Вывод содержимого папки Flask

Tags: python, flask

Столкнулся с проблемой. Имеется много много папок с файлами. Надо вывести содержимое на html страницу в виде дерева с возможностью открывать файлы в отдельном окне и с возможностью скачать. Не хочет создавать вручную страницу под каждый файл. Кто знает как такое можно реализовать на Flask

Answer (score 2):

Получаем содержимое папки через модуль os после чего формируем список из файлов и папок и выводим в html документ при помощи шаблонизатора и цикла for. Оказалась просто, хотя сначала так не казалось